# bootstrap-star-rating plugin causes an error with Capybara js enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, twitter-bootstrap-3, rspec, capybara

I have included bootstrap-star-rating plugin to Rails 5 app.

After including `*= require bootstrap-star-rating` to stylesheets I faced with an error while running Capybara specs with enabled JS (`js: true`). These specs fail only for pages, where bootstrap-star-rating plugin enabled. It works fine after removing `*= require bootstrap-star-rating` from stylesheet file.

An error has the following content:

```
Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"
 
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/img/loading.gif"
```

`/img/loading.gif` file presents only in node_modules/bootstrap-star-rating/img/loading.gif and uses only with this plugin CSS

Assets successfully compile and work well with the app.

Comment: I've found the solution by setting up `config.assets.debug = true` in `config/environments/test.rb`. But still confused what is wrong with 3rd party NPM package assets and Rails' assets pipeline.

Comment: I've just hit this too! Did you ever figure out what was wrong?